# Create a table with courses of a certain curriculum

Tags: views, nodes

I'm a newbie when it comes to Drupal. I already tried to do it with content types and views but can't seem to accomplish what I need.

I need to create a table with a list of curriculum. Each curriculum name should be a link. So, when you click on a certain curriculum, it'll take you to a page with a table that lists the courses for that curriculum.

Something like the following:

```
Curriculum List
| Name      | Total Credit Hours |
----------------------------------
| Drupal 7  |                 15 |
| WordPress |                 15 |
| Joomla!   |                 15 |
----------------------------------
```

Then, when user clicks on Drupal 7:

```
Drupal 7 Courses
| Name                                         | Credit Hours |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| Drupal 7 Essentials                          |           3  |
| Drupal 7 Advanced Training                   |           4  |
| Drupal 7: Reporting and Visualizing Data     |           4  |
| Drupal 7: Creating and Editing Custom Themes |           4  |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

If possible, I don't want to create this by writing a template file since I'm new to Drupal. If someone can at least point me in the right direction I will really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a vocabulary for Curriculum List ,then  add Drupal 7, wordpress etc as terms in your vocabulary.

Create a content type for 'Courses'. Link your Curriculum List taxonomy to courses content type.

Then create view to list your taxonomy term and Total Credit Hours  with format as table.

Create another view to list all courses, with a 'contextual filters' as taxonomy term id.

Link your first Curriculum view's taxonomy term to the courses view , eg: courses/2 where

courses is your course views display path and 2 is the term id.

Comment: How do I 'link my Curriculum List taxonomy to courses content type'?

Comment: How do I 'Create another view to list all courses, with a 'contextual filters' as taxonomy term id.'? :-S

Comment: 1) To link your content type to a taxonomy, go to structure content types->click manage fields -> Add a new field with type as 'term reference' and save it. On Field settings choose your Vocabulary                                                        2)To create a view with 'contextual filters' as taxonomy term id, refer following link  [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362360/drupal-7-views-filter-by-dynamic-taxonomy-term?lq=1) or in your view click add Contextual filters->choose Content: Has taxonomy term ID ->Provide default value ->choose 'Taxonomy term ID from URL'